# Why is the address of a variable defined inside a loop unchanged on each iteration?

Tags: c++

```
for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
    int j = i;
    cout << &j << endl;
}
```

This will output the same address of `j` in each iteration.  I also noticed the same behavior in C.  Shouldn't it be a different address for different iteration ?
In python different address is printed, couldn't verify it in java

```
for i in range(10):
    j = i
    print(hex(id(j)))
```

c++ -v on my system returns this

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3)
```

Comment: What compiler optimisations are you running?

Comment: Why should it be a different address? The compiler is free to reuse the same address.

Comment: You're not taking the address of the variable in Python. Python does not provide a way to do that.

Comment: Quite the opposite, it will most likely be located at the same location. Value you are getting in Python is not an address of a variable, but address of an object referenced by this variable. You cannot get address of variable in Python.

Comment: @user2357112 CPython allows you to do this. Object's id is just an address where it was allocated.

Comment: Try repeating that Python loop a few times (in the same program).

Comment: @Ivan It's the address of the object, not the address of the variable. Multiple variables may refer to the same object, and if so, `id` will return the same value for all those variables.

Comment: @hvd This is what I said few posts before.

Comment: @Ivan You were disagreeing with user2357112's claim that it's impossible to take the address of a variable in Python. That claim was actually correct.

Comment: Try turning off all compiler optimizations too - that may change what C++ does.

Comment: @Kieveli Highly unlikely. Even almost impossible. It is far more natural for it to have the same address every time.

Comment: Aside: in the Python test, change your print to `print(hex(id(j)),hex(id(i)))` and contemplate the result. Python variables aren't like C or C++ variables.

Comment: In addition, putting `print(hex(id(0)))` and `print(hex(id(1)))` after the loop could be a step towards enlightenment.

Comment: How about simply, Python is not Java is not C++.  They are all 3 different languages with different rules.  Doing such comparisons could put you on the slippery slope of trying to make one language work and look like the other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The address of a local variable is an implementation detail of the compiler.

When a local comes into scope like this, the compiler might reuse the same address it had before, or it might not.  You shouldn't depend on it either way.

In practice, with optimizations turned off, it's most likely simpler for the compiler to use the same address each time.  In fact, if function `a` were to call function `b` multiple times, the local variables of function `b` will most likely be in the same place each time the function is called.

But again, this is an implementation detail.  There's no guarantee this will be the case across different compilers, or on the same compiler with different optimization settings.

Comment: It's not just about a local coming into scope like this, as a local is guaranteed to have a address distinct from that of all other variables. It's also about the variable from the earlier loop iteration no longer existing.

Comment: @hvd: That is correct, existence is the key concept here, not scope. So that people have the correct terminology to discuss this: **Scope** is **where** the **name** of an object is visible. **Lifetime** is **when** an object **exists**. Scope exists only during compilation. Lifetime exists only during execution.

Answer (score 0):

> shouldn't it be a different address for different iteration ?

There's no requirement for it to be this way. In fact, on a common implementation where a local variable is located on a functions call frame (on the so called call stack), it's rather easy for the address to be unchanging. It's just reusing the same space, relative to the start of the frame.

> In python different address is printed

Because the implementation in Python is different. In each iteration `i` is reference for a **different** object in the range. It's not the same storage taking on a different object and value.

Answer (score 0):

The address is implementation defined. However, the variable will be created on a stack-like memory structure because of the requirement for objects to *deconstruct* in reverse order from their *constructing*.

So it is not allocating random pieces of memory from a heap (or the free store), it is likely re-using the same part of the stack memory structure each time round the loop.

If you think about it, at the beginning of each loop it creates the variable and then destroys it at the end of the loop -freeing up the memory it just occupied. It is not a surprise it then re-creates the object in the same place next time the loop starts.